# How to open a VBScript file with a variable?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm starting a VBScript sometimes from a Windows batch file:

```
FOR /F %%i IN (list.txt) DO vbscript.vbs
```

and I want to receive the `%%i` variable in the VBScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the VBScript with `%%i` as its argument:

```
FOR /F %%i IN (list.txt) DO vbscript.vbs %%i
```

and assign the argument to a variable inside the VBScript:

```
var = WScript.Arguments(0)
```